# How to get API Request/ Response time using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.1.0 for API parsing in my android application. I need the time taken by retrofit to parse the API.

How to obtain the Request/ response time using Retrofit 2.

Below is the Retrofit Rest Client Call I am using for API parsing.

```
public static class ServiceGenerated {
    static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                    return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                }
            })
            .build();


    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(RetrofitUtils.API_BASE_URL)
                    .client(httpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());


    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

Comment: do u want to log request/response time?

Comment: you may need to use interceptor. which is exactly shown your need here https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Comment: @darwin Yes I need the log for the request or response time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    }
```

also add

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

to your app module gradle file

Sample response:

```
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 07:33:23 GMT
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1470987074283
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1470987074422
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution provided. But still it doesnot provide any timeout log. How to print the logs using OkHttp.

Comment: you will get time log in your console as above

Comment: are u using HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY as log level?

Comment: How can we get the response time in the code from call object or request object?

Answer (score 26):

You can calculate the total round trip time by substracting the timestamp when response is received and timestamp when the request is sent. These two methods from the Response object will give you these two values

1. [`Response.sentRequestAtMillis()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#sentRequestAtMillis--)
2. [`Response.receivedResponseAtMillis()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#receivedResponseAtMillis--)

   ```
       RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url(url)
               .post(body)
               .build();
       Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       long tx = response.sentRequestAtMillis();
       long rx = response.receivedResponseAtMillis();
       System.out.println("response time : "+(rx - tx)+" ms");
   ```

Comment: this can't make an globle statistic

Answer (score 16):

It's easy you can find the `receivedResponseAtMillis()` and the `sendResponseAtMillis()` in the `raw()` part of the response and then you can calculate the difference

```
response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis()
response.raw().sendResponseAtMillis()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at `EventListener` from `okhttp` lib
https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/events/